# What git branch should I commit unit tests to?

Tags: git, unit-testing, version-control, git-flow

I'm currently following the ever-popular git workflow described [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

One thing it doesn't discuss is how to handle unit testing. Let's say I write some code and commit to `develop`. I want to write a test for it, but I don't want it in my `develop` history, I'd like to keep the tests separate so that when I look at `git log` I only see changes to the main code. However, if I commit the test to a separate `test` branch, I'll have to merge develop/test back and forth constantly, resulting in a ridiculous amount of merge commit clutter.

How do you manage unit testing in a git repository?

Comment: `I want to write a test for it, but I don't want it in my develop history`. tests are part of the development. when someone checks out your PR/branch/tag/commit/whatever, they should be able to run all the tests and see that your work works. Tests are usually in a dedicated folder, and main sources are in another. You can `git log` on the main folder, or filter in whatever git tool you use to only see changes in code. (However, a change in code should be accompanied by a change in the tests)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unit tests are part of your source tree: They evolve as your code evolves, and feature branches have their own unit tests that evolve as the features evolve. There's no reason to keep them in a separate branch.

Note that `git log` accepts a path parameter, so if you want to avoid seeing test-only log entries, you can do the filtering at that point. I typically keep my `src` and `testsrc` source folders separate and adjacent, so I can see changes to one or the other easily just by specifying `git log src` or `git log testsrc`.